# c# exception when parsing a string to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date time variable  `DateTime d` which has data.

I have string like this:

`11:00 - 12:00`

I want to take the date from the `d` variable then add the hour and minute from the string.

I did this:

```
string newStringDate = d.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") + " "+hourValue.Split('-')[0];
                    DateTime dd = DateTime.Parse(newStringDate);
```

I got excpetion that the string can't be transfered to date.

I debug the code and I can see that the `newStrinDate` = `2014-01-25 11:00`

what am i doing wrong please?

Comment: Which one do you want to parse `11:00 - 12:00` or `2014-01-25 11:00` ?

Comment: Then why did you post the first one? Isn't your question simply *How can I parse `2014-01-25 11:00`*

Comment: @L.B I wasn't sure that I am spliting the string correctly

Comment: What was hard to do when you tried to debug the result of *Split* ?

Comment: @L.B there was nothing hard with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
string newStringDate = d.ToString(@"yyyy\-MM\-dd") + " " + hourValue.Split('-')[0].Trim();
DateTime dd = DateTime.ParseExact(newStringDate, @"yyyy\-MM\-dd HH\:mm", null);
```

You can do even better (no need to convert original date to string):

```
DateTime dd = d.Date + DateTime.ParseExact(hourValue.Split('-')[0].Trim(), @"HH\:mm", null).TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: I got the same exception on the second line `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: @user3432257 Try updated answer. You have trailing space - that's the problem.

Comment: it works. thanks, will accept once the system allows +1

Comment: @user3432257 You're welcome. I added one-liner, which, I believe, is better way to handle it.